# Xpath - remove/elimiate duplicates & get position of a character & check for equality of character

Tags: xpath, duplicates, position, equality

I was asked to write some xpath queries on the following HTML code:

```
<catalog>
 <book id="bk101">
  <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
  <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
  <genre>Computer</genre>
  <shops>
   <shop name="Best Books">
    <price>44.95</price>
   </shop>
   <shop name="Books and More">
    <price>48.95</price>
   </shop>
  </shops>
  <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
  <description>
  An in-depth look at creating applications with XML.
  </description>
 </book>
```

..... 10 book in this style

```
</catalog>
```

The queries are:

a. Return all the shops that have books that cost less than 10 dollar.
   my query: `/catalog/book/shops/shop[price<10]`
   problem: return the same store node more than ones (because the same shop
   sells more than one book in less than 10 dollars price).
   **questionA**: how to remove/eliminate dulpicates?

b. Return all the authors that publish a book after 2000.
   my query: `/catalog/book[publish_date/text()[1]='2']/author` 
   problem: doesnt work, trying to get the first character of the publish_date 
   and check if it equals to 2.
   **questionB**: how to get the first character of a text node and check if it 
   euqals to other charater?

Comment: Note, there's no HTML here. This is XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Select `shop` such that there is no `shop` with `price` less than 10 and with the same `name` tag before

```
/catalog/book/shops/shop[price<10 and not(@name = preceding::shop[price<10]/@name)]
```

2) Take substring before minus, cast to number and compare with 2000. To remove doubles you can use the same trick as in 1)

```
/catalog/book[number(substring-before(publish_date,"-")) >= 2000]/author
```